# What features should be prioritized when buying a camera intended for wildlife/zoo photography?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, body, wildlife

I currently use a Canon 750D and I'm thinking about upgrading my camera body (followed by lenses) in the future.

I use the camera for various types of photography but predominantly wildlife and zoo photography.

To decide what to buy I'd like to know what features of a camera should perhaps be prioritized knowing that it will be mostly used for said purpose.

**I'm no expert (hence why I'm here) but here are my thoughts so far:**

- Full frame, for low-light situations such as dark reptile vivariums (Reptiles happen to be my favourite subject). Also, I'm assuming this would allow for higher shutter speeds which is obviosuly good for moving animals.
- AI Servo mode, again for moving animals
- Higher fps, for continuous shooting
- More AF points

What else am I missing?

**Additional details**

I'd like to stick with Canon due to lenses and familiarity etc. I've been looking at the Canon 6D Mark ii and would appreciate any input from those who have used it or know more etc

Here's a comparison of the above details between my Canon 750D and a Canon 6D Mark ii

- Crop / Full frame
- Both have AI Servo
- 5fps / 6.5fps
- 19 points / 45 points

Comment: What lenses are you using? Trading up to a faster lens might be the solution, rather than a new camera.

Comment: Admittedly, quite cheap ones. However, upgrading them wouldn't completely solve low light issues. Also, if I was to upgrade to a full frame I would likely follow it with full frame lenses. Currently I use 50mm 1.8f prime, Tarom 70-300mm Di LD Macro, a 10-18mm USM and the 18-55mm kit lens

Comment: So the nifty fifty will be plenty fast enough. The Tamron is nowhere near. I have one, it likes a lot of light & a lot of time to focus, on a subject that doesn't move much.  I'm Nikon rather than Canon, but I have a Nikon 18-300 which wipes the floor with the Tamron, focuses in milliseconds rather than decades ;) in any light that I don't have to get my nifty f1.4 out for. The Tamron is slightly sharper at the long end, so I use it in the studio with lots of light.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yep, I use MF exclusively with the Tamron xD

Comment: You'd be wasting a 6D Mark II using it with that Tamron 70-300. Your other two zoom lenses won't even mount on a FF camera. And while the 50/1.8 is a *great value* for what it costs, it's not really a *great lens* compared to other fast primes in the same focal length range.

Comment: @Xander The S/N ratio difference between an APS-C and FF camera of roughly the same technology in low light is about one stop. The difference between f/5.6 and f/2.8 is two stops. The difference between F/5.6 and f/2 is three stops.

Comment: @MichaelC I'd be replacing the tamron to a Canon EF 70-300 IS USM probably if I were to upgrade. Would you mind explaing the signal-noise ratio? Do you mean that f/5.6 on a FF would be similar light to f/4.2 on a crop?

Comment: One stop from f/5.6 is f/4. You get about the same amount of noise at f/5.6 and, say, 1/500 second @ ISO 3200 on a FF camera as you would get at f/4 and 1/500 second @ISO 1600 on  an APS-C body.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that at f/5.6 on both cameras you'd need to use 1/250 @ ISO 1600 with the APS-C camera to get the same noise as 1/500 @ ISO 3200 on the FF.

Comment: @MichaelC So effectively, upgrading to a FF wouldn't improve low-light photography too much? (In the case of a 750D vs 6D mark ii)

Comment: @Xander One stop is fairly significant. In many situations it can be the difference between getting the shot or not. But it isn't a magic bullet that eliminates all noise as some folks seem to think. There are situations where even a FF camera and a very fast lens aren't enough. It's one stop. A good lens on a mediocre camera will do better than a mediocre lens on a good camera almost every single time.

Answer (score 2):

If you like reptiles that tend to be indoors, you want something that handles noise well and has a wide aperture and fast focus. Others have pointed out up and down the comments section, that usually the answer would start with lenses, and I agree. In your case, I'd probably get one decent prime lens with wide aperture (2.8 or better, ideally wider than 2) at the perfect focal length for your scaly friends, and then jump on the 6D.

I've owned a few 6Ds and I'm a huge fan. I'll take them anywhere. They're rugged and versatile. For your question about priorities, here are a few thoughts.
If you like holding the shutter down for some serious FPS, then maybe that's important for you, but it hasn't been a high priority for me.

I DO like the bump up in number of focal points on the 6D mark ii, but in your case, it may not always be that useful, because the reptile exhibits will tend to be fairly visually busy, and you'll want to set your focal point on the reptile (or other critters) eyeballs, directly. The number of points are useful for letting the camera decide the optimal middle ground of scene. I'm not sure when this is ideal - maybe a family portrait of 250 reptiles, and you want to be fair? Or you're doing a wide-angle shot that takes in the entire orangutan exhibit, and none of them have earned the limelight of your focus.